# Meaning of "Ship it!"

Tags: meaning

I wrote the letter

> Dear XXX,
>
> I am writing to inform that I found the workaround solution for
>   bug...

and got the answer

> Great! **Ship it!**

If I correctly guessed, *Great!* means approval of my solution, but what does *Ship it!* mean? Is it slang or some special emotion?

Comment: I think that in order for anyone to single-handedly close something as "general reference", they should be required to provide that proverbial single link to the proverbial standard reference. Just saying.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There's a (in)famous software development quote, relayed with tongue firmly in cheek: "Hey! It compiles! Ship it!"

In software development, there are many steps a conscientious developer must go through between writing the code and sending ("shipping") the completed product to the end-user. A willingness on the part of the developer to ship as soon as the code *compiles* indicates either extreme hubris or carelessness: no testing has been performed by the developer (to verify that the changes work and haven't broken anything else), no 3rd-party testing has been performed (to verify that the change doesn't break other systems and is acceptable to users), no documentation has been written...

So when used by *someone else* in regard to your work, "Ship it!" implies confidence in your abilities: "You're one in a million, man — I have confidence that it'll work as you say it does."

Comment: +1 I'd just typed more or less the same thing, complete with the "It compiles!" joke :)

Comment: @Shog9: Dude, I really liked your [meta post about closing more questions because of general reference](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity). . I'm not sure where I stand on this question (other than I think it is only somewhat general reference, but could benefit by some answer (so I voted to reopen). But, it is obviously in the area of general ref, and yet you answered. Seems kinda weird. By your meta post **shouldn't you be discouraging this kind of question** much less answering it?

Comment: Heh... You made a good point in comments on that question, @Mitch: I'm on your meta, critiquing your site, and here, closing questions... But I don't exactly have any *skin in the game*. Then I saw this question, and the lousy, dictionary-link top answer, and thought it'd be a good test-case: I posted what I felt was a reasonably informed answer (something that *didn't* come from a dictionary or the first few Google results), but left the question alone. If you guys close+delete the question (and I'm not saying you shouldn't...) I'll take my lumps and lose the rep.

Comment: @Mitch: I think Shog9's answer demonstrates exactly why this question is **not** general reference. There's more to this phrase than what's in the dictionary.

Comment: @Martha: I may be arguing against myself or just acting via RegDwights chat comments. Nothing is clear cut for me here.

Comment: @Shog9: all you've said has been very good and well-intentioned (and I mostly agree) but yes I guess it must be the lack of "skin in the game" that confused me.

Comment: My goal in all of this, @Mitch, is to make clear the idea that it's *you guys* who ultimately determine the level of quality found here. Not me, not the Community Team, not Jeff... You, the folks here every day, watching the questions roll in. We can point out problems, spend a few minutes closing or leaving comments... But long-term, it's up to y'all to decide *what*, exactly, constitutes an issue for the site - and what the solution will be.

Answer (score 18):

*Ship it* means *[deliver the goods](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/come-up-with-the-goods#come-up-with-the-goods__1)*. He is telling you to go ahead with executing your solution.

Answer (score 14):

"Shipping" in the software sense means to deliver it to the customer.  It derives from the old practice of literally shipping boxes containing disks/CDs in the mail.

@Shog9 had a good description of the origin of "Ship it!", but I think in modern practice it no longer has any particular implication of confidence or recklessness.  I have seen it used in several ways:

- Go ahead and implement the solution.
- Get it to the customer as soon as possible.
- (usually tongue in cheek) As @shog9 described, "Who needs to test it?  Just ship it!"

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it means *Send it to me*, by extension of the use of *ship* meaning *to transport goods* by ship or by some other means.

Comment: It definitely doesn't mean to send to the guy who wrote it, unless that guy is the customer. Most customers would actually say "Send it to me". It's a managerial/dev-lead choice to say to "ship it".